# Angular 5 - Dynamically creating components

Tags: angular, angular5

Let's say I have a method `generateHTML(someAttributes: string) : string`.
Calling it with `style="color:#fff"` would return:

```
<div style="color:#fff">Test</div>
```

It works because I'm calling bypassSecurityTrustHtml() on the resulting string.

Now the problem I have is this one: the method now returns something like

```
<div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <some-selector [stuff]="test"></some-selector>
    <p>Other text</p>
</div>
```

`some-selector` is not interpreted by Angular.

I've been trying to use a `ViewRef` but it doesn't working in my case because I need to generate a bunch of stuff in one go and the ordering is important (`ViewRef` adds the component at the end).

Hopefully I'm missing something.
Thank you all for reading!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: check this article [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e#2b99)